# Why does PostgreSQL's shell shows me a different OS version instead of my real operating system?

Tags: linux, postgresql

When I execute the following command:

```
SELECT version();
```

I get:

```
PostgreSQL 9.6.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16), 64-bit
```

What does Red Hat 4.4.7-16 means? I am running PostgreSQL on Debian 9 so, why this shows me Red Hat instead?

Comment: Because it's where it was *built*?

Comment: How did you install this thing? It seems very odd you're using a RedHat built Postgres server.

Comment: I just followed the steps of PostgreSQL site, I downloaded the graphical installer directly from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads#linux, I selected version 9.6 and Linux-x86-64 OS and I just downloaded this. Do I did something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does **not** report your OS, but the software it was compiled with, i.e. GCC compiler version 4.4.7. More specifically: 4.4.7-16 (update 16) on Red Hat OS.

Your are running on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (that is Debian 9 I suspect). See `uname -a`.

Just checked one of our servers (Debian 8):

`PostgreSQL 9.6.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit`

So, the Debian version should be built on Debian. See comment tadman.